# Mod_Spdy not running on Centos

Tags: apache, google-chrome, centos, mod-spdy

I'm setting up Apache on Centos the way I have done in the past, but for some reason mod_spdy is not running. I'm following the instructions here:

https://developers.google.com/speed/spdy/mod_spdy/

When I run **rpm -U mod-spdy-beta_current_x86_64.rpm** I get this message:

```
warning: mod-spdy-beta_current_x86_64.rpm: Header V4 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 7fac5991: NOKEY
package mod-spdy-beta-0.9.4.3-420.x86_64 is already installed
```

If I open **chrome://net-internals/#spdy** and my site in another tab, it doesn't show my site. If I look in the network panel, I don't see the x-mod-spdy header.

Update: If I use Firefox firebug, I see the x-mod-spdy header. I don't see my site in Chrome spdy sessions, but I see other sites in it.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: I have the exact same issue on my Oracle Linux. I actually have two servers (my QA and Dev) system and both shows the same, setup in the last few days.. My guess, that something is wrong with the current mod-spdy package.

Comment: I had two more servers where I have installed mod_spdy more than 6 months ago and they used to show up as SPDY in Chrome and not anymore. The mod_spdy rpm didn't change, so it is either a Chrome issue or Apache. I keep looking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok it seems the issue is that Chrome 40.x dropped support for SPDY/3 and only supports SPDY/3.1, but the mod_spdy module for Apache only supports SPDY/3, so basically no SPDY for Chrome users if you use Apache as a web server.

mod_spdy is currently in a bad state where either Google nor Apache is maintaining it after Google donated it to the Asf. Google recently made the statement that they will drop the SPDY support from Chrome in early 2016, but what they forgot to say that they started dropping older versions of SPDY already (including SPDY/3) (I like these partially true statements by the way), so basically if you are on Apache then for your Chrome users you can't provide SPDY short of implementing SPDY/3.1 yourself.

So, how was that "do no evil"? :-)

See details: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mod-spdy-discuss/FPEj0zG5I0Y
and https://code.google.com/p/mod-spdy/issues/detail?id=100&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

One option you might consider is switching to Nginx and using SPDY/3.1 over there.